# firebase rules, owner can delete

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new with Firebase. I'm trying to set up the rules, and I'm using this rule to let only the user comment owner be able to write. The problem is that it requires the poster id (the owner id) but when I try to remove the node it doesn't work because I can't send the poster id with it (can I?). This is the rule:

```
"infinity_comments":{
    "country": {
         "$countryid": {
            "$postid":  {
               "$pushid": {
                    ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid ) || (data.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid)"
                 } 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

This is how i try to delete the comment:

```
firebase.database().ref('infinity_comments/country/countryid/postid/pushid/').remove(function(error){
    if (!error) {
        alert('success');
    }
    else {
        alert(error)
    }
})
```

I get permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting permission denied because delete is actually a write operation with a null value. You can update your rule, adding a new OR clause like below:

```
".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid )
|| (data.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid)
|| (data.child('posterid').val() == auth.uid && !newData.exists())"
```

Comment: its not working , still getting permission denied :/

Comment: its working now thanks so much, please correct your code the last line, its auth.uid. u put it auth.id thats why didnt work

Comment: @SandraLopez, I corrected the code, thanks for pointing the error out!